# How to ignore unavailable API data in an async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, frontend, web-frontend

Just starting out with React JS. I am developing a coin exchange web application which displays the cryptocurrency prices, tickers, names, etc. The problem is, I wanted to include the logos (which is coming from another API) in the display but it encounters an error. The coin icons API which I'm using does not include every coin in the marketlist today. How can I tell the application to just ignore the ones which does not have an icon and proceed rendering everything?

```
const componentDidMount = async () => {
    const priceInquiry = await axios.get('https://api.coinpaprika.com/v1/tickers');
    const coinApiURL = 'https://cryptoicons.org/api/color/';

    let filteredRank = priceInquiry.data.sort(function(a, b)
        { return a.rank - b.rank}).slice(0, 20);

    let newCoinData = filteredRank.map(function(coin){
        return {
          key: coin.id,
          name: coin.name,
          ticker: coin.symbol,
          icon: getIcon(coin.symbol),
          balance: 0,
          price: //some function that gets the latest price,
          rank: coin.rank
        }
      }
    )

    async function getIcon(ticker){
      const lowercaseTicker = ticker.toLowerCase();
      const response = await axios.get('https://cors.bridged.cc/' + coinApiURL + lowercaseTicker+'/200')
          .catch((error) => undefined); // I tried setting the value to undefined but still getting 
                                                 // errors
      return response.data;
    }
```

Sorry if this is a super noob question. Any help is greatly appreciated... Also if you have noticed some weird practice please tell me so I would know (and learn from it!).

Comment: What happens if you replace your catch with `.catch((error) => ({ data: undefined }));` ?

Answer (score 0):

you are calling a wrong url api getIcon function. i consoled log this and it showed you are calling **https://cors.bridged.cc/https://cryptoicons.org/api/color/uni/200** and this wrong and you certainly get 404 error